# Lightswitch HTML: error: value cannot be null. Paramater name: property

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

has anyone come accross this issue before, all of a sudden one of my details pickers has started displaying this error:

[image]

within the database this particular field can be null, and also with the staff tablem which references it, this can also be null, Im not sure on what I should currently do... If i press on the plus symbol however the results are displayed, thankyou for any assistance in this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done these steps to get it working again, however I do not know what caused this issue:

1. Removed the foreign key between the 2 tables in question
2. Updated the data source
3. Re-added the foreign key
4. Updated the data source

If any one know's what could have caused this error, or a better way of fixing this (as the above does mean the details between the 2 have to be put back on the screens they are on). I would be grateful.